# How does Getstream.io's own_reactions work? Thought it would contain the reactions from the user fetching

Tags: getstream-io

Getstream.io's own_reactions are storing all reactions, not just the ones from the user fetching. I thought it would contain the reactions from the user fetching the activities, or maybe even the own reactions of the user who created the activity.

In the documentation, it makes it seem like own_reactions would contain the reactions from the user fetching:

> ```
> "# read bob's timeline and include most recent reactions to all activities and her own reactions"
> ```

https://getstream.io/docs_rest/#reactions

But there's not much other info about this. 
In this code, for example:

```
let feed = client.feed('user', 'alice', streamUserToken);    
let response = await feed.get({ limit: 30,  enrich: true, reactions: {"counts": true, "recent": true, "own": true} })
```

I expect to see only Alice's own reactions, but instead I get all reactions, regardless of who they came from...

Comment: that's indeed the expected behavior, can you post the response output here?

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli here is a picture showing the output from the console, side by side with the UI: https://imgur.com/a/PHBllBv

The user is Banksy (the actual user ID is a hash) but you can see in the output that the own_reactions contain comments/reactions from other users too (Frida Kahlo).

Does own_reactions work by checkin the user_id of the reaction?

Comment: @ValentinPerez Have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

you have to specify the user_id when you read the feed (ie. different users can read the same feed)

make sure to pass user_id="alice" to feed.get

[click here](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-python/issues/92)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?